# Is there a way to open hdf5 files with the POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED flag?

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu, memory-management, h5py

We are working with large (1.2TB) uncompressed, unchunked hdf5 files with h5py in python for a machine learning application, which requires us to work through the full dataset repeatedly, loading slices of ~15MB individually in a randomized order. We are working on a linux (Ubuntu 18.04) machine with 192 GB RAM. We noticed that the program is slowly filling the cache. When total size of cache reaches size comparable with full machine RAM (free memory in top almost 0 but plenty ‘available’ memory) swapping occurs slowing down all other applications. In order to pinpoint the source of the problem, we wrote a separate minimal example to isolate our dataloading procedures - but found that the problem was independent of each part of our method.

We tried:
Building numpy memmap and accessing requested slice:

```
#on init:
f = h5py.File(tv_path, 'r')
hdf5_event_data = f["event_data"]
self.event_data = np.memmap(tv_path, mode="r", shape=hdf5_event_data.shape,                                           
                            offset=hdf5_event_data.id.get_offset(),dtype=hdf5_event_data.dtype)
self.e = np.ones((512,40,40,19))

#on __getitem__:
self.e = self.event_data[index,:,:,:19]
return self.e
```

Reopening the memmap on each call to getitem:

```
#on __getitem__:
self.event_data = np.memmap(self.path, mode="r", shape=self.shape,
                                            offset=self.offset, dtype=self.dtype)
self.e = self.event_data[index,:,:,:19]
return self.e
```

Addressing the h5 file directly and converting to a numpy array:

```
#on init:
f = h5py.File(tv_path, 'r')
hdf5_event_data = f["event_data"]
self.event_data = hdf5_event_data
self.e = np.ones((512,40,40,19))

#on __getitem__:
self.e = self.event_data[index,:,:,:19]
return self.e
```

We also tried the above approaches within pytorch Dataset/Dataloader framework - but it made no difference.

We observe high memory fragmentation as evidenced by /proc/buddyinfo. Dropping the cache via sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches doesn’t help while application is running. Cleaning cache before application starts removes swapping behaviour until cache eats up the memory again - and swapping starts again.

Our working hypothesis is that the system is trying to hold on to cached file data which leads to memory fragmentation. Eventually when new memory is requested swapping is performed even though most memory is still ‘available’.

As such, we turned to ways to change the Linux environment’s behaviour around file caching and found this post . Is there a way to call the POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED  flag when opening an h5 file in python or a portion of that we accessed via numpy memmap, so that this accumulation of cache does not occur? In our use case we will not be re-visiting that particular file location for a long time (till we access all other remaining ‘slices’ of the file)

Comment: Those `self.e=np.ones...` statements are useless.  We don't pre-allocate/define variables in python.

Comment: just trying to show what's being loaded :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`os.posix_fadvise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.posix_fadvise) to tell the OS how regions you plan to load will be used. This naturally requires a bit of low-level tweaking to determine your file descriptor, and get an idea of the regions you plan on reading.

The easiest way to get the file descriptor is to supply it yourself:

```
pf = open(tv_path, 'rb')
f = h5py.File(pf, 'r')
```

You can now set the advice. For the entire file:

```
os.posix_fadvise(os.fileno(pf), 0, f.id.get_filesize(), os.POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED)
```

Or for a particular dataset:

```
os.posix_fadvise(os.fileno(pf), hdf5_event_data.id.get_offset(),
                 hdf5_event_data.id.get_storage_size(), os.POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED)
```

**Other things to look at**

H5py does its own [chunk caching](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/file.html#chunk-cache). You may want to try turning this off:

```
f = h5py.File(..., rdcc_nbytes=0)
```

As an alternative, you may want to try using one of the other [drivers](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/file.html#file-drivers) provided in h5py, like `'sec2'`:

```
f = h5py.File(..., driver='sec2')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! We have been pursuing the os.posix_fadvise route (our dataset is unchunked and the different drivers doesn't seem to help). It seems that setting the advice only serves to clear the cache of associated file data once when it is called, but does not deter the kernel from caching data from the file in future. This means that we must set the advice regularly - do you know if we can cut down on this overhead by setting the advice only for the chunk we retrieve, or if it will be just as slow?

Comment: @calum-macdonald33. I suspect that setting the advice is a relatively trivial operation even by itself, and even more so when you compare it to the I/O. I doubt it would even show up above the noise in a proper benchmark

Comment: When loading via a numpy memmap, the call to posix_fadvise takes a huge amount of time and seems to increase with each call. This doesn't happen when indexing the h5 dataset directly. We observed this both when accessing the data directly and when doing so with a Torch dataloader in multiple threads. How can we continue to use the memmap (the access is much faster) while also supplying the advice to the kernel?

Comment: From the man pages for posix_fadvise, under FADV_DONT_NEED, '  Requests  to  discard partial pages are ignored.  It is preferable to preserve needed data than unneeded data.  If the application requires that data be considered for discarding, then offset and must be page-aligned.' How do I go about page-aligning offset and len in this case?